# Calling a function if an operation is not true

Tags: javascript, function, variables, if-statement

I have not seen anything that specifically answers this question.
I intend to develop a text-based game that involves an action occurring every time an idle bar fills up(every x seconds passes)
I'm just trying to figure out the very basic layout of my javascript that will make the battling system in this game.

I'm trying to make the computer re-calculate pDamThisRound if pDamThisRound is not > baseD which is this case is 10.

If it is greater than baseD my code works and prints pDamThisRound. But if it isn't the code just prints nothing.

```
var baseD = 10;
var pStr = 25;
var pDam = Math.floor((baseD + pStr) / 2);
var pDamThisRound;

var pDamTR  = function() {
    pDamThisRound = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2 * pDam));
};

pDamTR();

if(pDamThisRound > baseD) {
document.getElementById("h").innerHTML = pDamThisRound;
}

else {
pDamTR();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qfnvf1y8/4/

Comment: You need to *iterate*. If the test fails, your code does calculate a new value, but it never goes back to check the condition again.

Comment: In your else branch, you dont print anything...

Comment: Try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/qfnvf1y8/7/

Comment: I can't believe how simple that was. For some reason I was thinking that based if my parameters for the if statement weren't met it would cycle through the if statement again after calling pDamTR again. Sorry for posting such a rookie mistake. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

> the code just prints nothing

That's because there isn't any code which prints anything.  Look at your `else` block:

```
else {
    pDamTR();
}
```

What does that function do?:

```
var pDamTR  = function() {
    pDamThisRound = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2 * pDam));
};
```

Nowhere do you produce any output.

Basically, if you want to print something then, well, *print something*.  Just like you *already do* in your `if` block.  For example:

```
document.getElementById("h").innerHTML = "something";
```

Comment: was my answer useful? If it wasn't let me know, I can clarify it

Comment: @SebastianGabrielVinci: Well, it wasn't particularly useful *to me*.  But then, I wasn't the one asking the question.

Comment: sorry, I scrolled from the bottom and missed the box. Answers and Questions boxes look awfully the same.

Answer (score 1):

The function pDamTR is probably executing, the problem is that its assigning something to a variable, but doing nothing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, a corrected version with a while operator:

https://jsfiddle.net/qfnvf1y8/6/

```
var baseD = 10;
var pStr = 25;
var pDam = Math.floor((baseD + pStr) / 2);
var pDamThisRound;

var pDamTR  = function() {
    pDamThisRound = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2 * pDam));
};

pDamTR();

while(pDamThisRound <= baseD) {
    pDamTR();
}

if(pDamThisRound > baseD) {
document.getElementById("h").innerHTML = pDamThisRound;
}

else {
pDamTR();
}
```

Regards,

Eugene

Answer (score 0):

Several mistakes:

1) your else branch does not print anything
2) if you want `pDamThisRound > baseD` you need a while loop

```
while(pDamThisRound <= baseD) {
    pDamTR();
}

printpDamTR();

function printpDamTR(){
    document.getElementById("h").innerHTML = pDamThisRound;
}
```

The function `printpDamTR` would not be necessary, but it generally is a good idea to encapsulate such things, as you are probably going to use it more often. Also it increases the maintainability of your code since you loosen the dependencies between your JS and your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` to help you, with something like this:

```
var baseD = 10;
var pStr = 25;
var pDam = Math.floor((baseD + pStr) / 2);
var timeoutDuration = 3000; // 3 seconds


window.setTimeout(function () { 
  // execute the check and the update logic here

  var pDamThisRound = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2 * pDam));

  if(pDamThisRound > baseD) {
    document.getElementById("h").innerHTML = pDamThisRound;
  }

}, timeoutDuration);
```

This will execute the check every 3 seconds